# Return array of functions as an array of booleans

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm working on updating some old projects and I am trying to find a source or an example of something I'm trying to accomplish.

**what I have**

```
// sample object of functions
var functions = {
    required : function(value){
        return value.length > 0;
    },
    isObject : function(value){
        return typeof value == 'object';
    }
};
```

Above is a sample of functions in an object. What I want to know is can the following be done:

**pseudo code**

```
//user input
var funcs = [required(''), isObject({key : 'v'})];

// what the function I'm building will process, in a sense
functions[funcs[i]](//arguments from funcs[i]);

// what would remain after each function
funcs = [false, true] // with an end result of false
```

I'm not 100% sure that this can't be done, I'm just not sure how in the slightest something like this would be able to come about. Let's bounce some ideas around here and see what we come up with.

Let me know if you all need any clarification of anything I asked. Thank you ahead of time for all help!

**clarification on what I am trying to achieve**

The object of functions is not finite, there can be any amount of functions for this specific program I am writing. They are going to be predefined, so user input is not going to be an issue. I need to be able to determine what function is called when it is passed, and make sure any arguments passed with said function are present and passed as well. So when I pass `required('')`, I need to be able to go through my object of functions and find `functions['required']` and passed the empty string value with it. So like this `functions['required']('')`.

**other issues**

The functions object is private access and the user won't have direct access to it.

Comment: Your `functions` variable is not an array; it is an object with properties `required` and `isObject`. Are you trying to match up (pairwise) an array of functions (not what you currently have) and an array of arguments and end up with an array of function return values?

Comment: yes that's what I meant, haha, sorry long day at work

Comment: The problem here is that objects properties don't have a guaranteed order. How do you want to match up the functions with the order of the arguments array?

Comment: That's the issue I've been running into, because basically what I'm going to need to figure out first is how to get the name of the function that was passed in the array, and get it's arguments so I can do something like `func_passed_in.call(this, arguments_from_func_passed_in);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this.

```
var functions = {
    required : function(value){
        return value.length > 0;
    },
    isObject : function(value){
        return typeof value == 'object';
    }
};

// Because these values are user inputs, they should be strings,
// so I enclosed them in quotes.
var funcs = ["required('')", "isObject({key: 'v'})"];

funcs.map(function(e) {
    return eval('functions.' + e);
});
```

Running this should gives you an array of return values from the functions in the object.

Comment: This is the best answer yet! now, if we can figure out how to get it to work without the quotes in `var funcs` this will be money

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, this could be done with:

```
var tests = [functions.required(''), functions.isObject({key: 'v'})];
```

If that's all you need, consider that my answer.

For a more general approach, the right tool here seems to be [`Arrays.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). However, since you have an object containing all your functions instead of an array of functions, you'll need some way to make the correspondence. You can easily do this with a separate array of property names (e.g., `['required', 'isObject']`). Then you could do something like this:

```
var functions = {
    required : function(value){
        return value.length > 0;
    },
    isObject : function(value){
        return typeof value == 'object';
    }
};
var args = ['', {key: 'v'}];

var results = ['required', 'isObject'].map(
    function(test, i) {
        return functions[test](args[i]);
    }
);
```

Of course, if `functions` were an array instead of an object, you could simplify this:

```
var functions = [
    /* required : */ function(value){
        return value.length > 0;
    },
    /* isObject : */ function(value){
        return typeof value == 'object';
    }
];
var args = ['', {key: 'v'}];

var results = functions.map(
    function(test, i) {
        return test(args[i]);
    }
);
```

If you wanted to encapsulate this a bit, you could pass the `args` array as a second argument to `map()`, in which case inside the function you would use `this[i]` instead of `args[i]`.

Comment: No get that part, and this is similar to what I'm currently doing, but I'm trying to simplify it even further essentially `var tests = ['required', 'isObject'];` would be `var tests = [required(''), isObject({key: v})];` and your sample doesn't work if I have 20 functions, because I will.

Comment: @MarkHill - In that case, I don't really understand what problem you are having. See the edited start to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible.  Something like this:

```
var results = [];
var value = "value_to_pass_in";

for(var f in functions)
{
    results.push(f.call(this, value));
}
```

UPDATE:

```
function superFunc(value)
{
    var results = [];

    for(var f in functions)
    {
        results.push(f.call(this, value));
    }

    return results;
}

superFunc("value_to_pass_in");
```

Comment: your solution requires two pieces, which is how I'm doing it now. I want that combined into one, essentially I want to be able to do `f('value_to_pass_in')`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `map` function. You can mimic it like this (I guess if you want one line):

https://jsfiddle.net/khoorooslary/88gh2yeh/

```
var inOneLine = (function() {
    var resp = {};
    var i = 0;
    var fns = {
      required : function(value){
          return value.length > 0;
      },
      isObject : function(value){
          return typeof value == 'object';
      }
    };
    for (var k in  fns) resp[k] = fns[k](arguments[i++]);
    return resp;
}).apply(null,  [ '' , {key : 'v'}]);

console.log(inOneLine);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The object of functions is literally infinite the one I'm currently using has about twenty functions in it right now. So any of those functions can be called. I need to be able to identify which function was called, and then pass the passed arguments with it, to said named function. I like your track of thinking though

Answer (score 0):

```
var functions = {
    required : function(value){
        return value.length > 0;
    },
    isObject : function(value){
        return typeof value == 'object';
    }
};

var funcs = ["required('')", "isObject({key: 'v'})"];

function f(funcs){
  return funcs.map(function(e) {
      return eval('functions.' + e);
  });
}

console.log(f(funcs));
```